# Laravel project doesn't find custom package

Tags: laravel

I'm separating a project into framework code and custom code. The framework code is going onto a Laravel package. I have an existing library to which I'm adding the framework package, though they currently reside in separate directories. My composer.json `autoload.psr4` is thus:

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/",
    "MyLibrary\\": "../MyLibrary/",
    "MyLibrary\\Framework\\": "../framework/src/"
  },
```

Per the Laraval documentation I added an `extra` section to composer.json:

```
"extra": {
  "laravel": {
    "providers": [
      "MyLibrary\\Framework\\ServiceProvider"
    ]
  }
}
```

However, when I `artisan vendor:publish`, MyLibrary\Framework\ServiceProvider isn't in the provider list. Nor do any of the tags. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong aside from the unorthodox location of my namespaced files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your composer.json file should be like

```
  "repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "packages/your-vendor/basic",
        "options": {
            "symlink": true 
        }
    }
   ],
    "require": {
        "your-vendor/your-package": "dev-master"
    },
```

and then in package's composer.json

```
"extra": {
  "laravel": {
    "providers": [
      "MyLibrary\\Framework\\ServiceProvider"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Change ` "url": "packages/your-vendor/basic"` to `"url": "../framework"`.